# How to get a row that one column's value in this row has appear more than 100 times in this table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a courseinfo table in MySql,

it has four columns

```
id INT(10), cno INT(10), sno INT(10), cname VARCHAR(10)
```

I want to have the cname's value where the corresponding cno appears more than 100 times in this table.

Example:

```
1,10,12, math
2,8, 13, science
3,8, 9, science
4,8, 10, science,
```

So what I want is to find the cname if cno appear more than 100 times.

BTW, the cno always correspond to cname.

Does the function COUNT() help?

Thanks!

Comment: Google, didn't find a answer.

Comment: And someone says using count(), I am not sure, so I come here

Comment: It always correspont cname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT cname
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY cname
HAVING COUNT(cname) > 100
```

or

```
SELECT cno, cname
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY cno, cname
HAVING COUNT(cno) > 100
```

or just

```
SELECT cname
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY cno
HAVING COUNT(cno) > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a 'group' function on the column we are not grouping by

Untested code:

```
SELECT cno, max(cname) as cname,
FROM courseinfo
GROUP BY cno
HAVING count(cno) > 100
```